# Creating a directory that is read only

Tags: windows, file, permissions, filesystems, directory

I need to know if it is possible to create a read only directory from windows command line.

I know it is possible to use chmod and make files read only. But what I need is to create a folder and then immediately set it as read only upon creation. Trying to create new files inside this directory should then throw an error.

This can be done manually by modifying folder permissions using the gui. But, I need to do it from cmd for some tests.

I tried

> attrib +r dirPath

But this only works for files and not for the whole directory.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

A background to me problem. I need to test the behavior of a software that writes some text files. I want to test a use-case when I ask the software to write to a read only directory. I want to see I handle the exceptions correctly and inform users appropriately.

Comment: icacls.exe is the way to set permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by immediately -- as soon as the directory is created or after files have been added? Or are you creating an empty directory? If it's immediate and non-empty, then surely someone has the right to add files. Either way, you can only implement this at the directory level for a file system that supports security, such as NTFS. There's no way to disallow adding files to a FAT32 directory. Deleting files can be disallowed by individually setting the readonly attribute on each file, or by opening the files with read, write, or delete access and without sharing delete access.

Comment: This also seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), assuming you're trying to create an *empty* read-only directory.  Such a directory is pretty useless since it can't hold anything, which raises the question of *why* you need to create it.  I suspect that *why* is your real problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I hope my edit makes my problem more clear